# OnPause Andengine -Game hangs for few seconds after pressing power button

Tags: android, andengine

I am developing a game using andengine. The game hangs for few seconds after pressing the power button.

Steps:

Launch game
  Press power button

Launch game again – game goes to pause mode, but hangs (can’t resume game for a few seconds)

// loadSprite.setVisible(false);

```
protected void onPause()
{
    super.onPause(); // game pause method
   loadSprite.setVisible(true);
    this.mEngine.onPause();
}



@Override
```

protected void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

```
   super.onResume();        
    this.mEngine.onResume();
```

}

In manifest file in activity placed

```
<android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard|keyboardHidden">
```

loadSprite is visible after 4-5 seconds only. .

I want to display loadSprite immediately .. How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Can you post your cod of on resume also.

Comment: s. .i updated.. In this game i loaded many images. may be its problem ?